# Are android fragments like iframe in HTML?

Tags: android, html

I understand that android is a completely different thing than browser programming.
But coming from a web development background, I wanted to undertand what fragments are supposed to be used for ?
Are they similar to the concept of iframes in an HTML page having its  own UI and can be added to any other page?

If not then what is tje general use-case of android fragments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are reusable parts of your applications. You can have for example two different Activities using same Fragment. You may want to read Fragments [Design Philosophy](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#Design) in the android documentation.

Here's also short description from the same documentation page:

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an
>   Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to
>   build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You
>   can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has
>   its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can
>   add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub
>   activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

Comment: So, Ideally I should always be using fragments on tablets ?

Comment: Yes, but also on smartphones. Fragments is current recommended method to design your application. If you don't use them, you will get warnings in Eclipse. Fragments can be now used even with android API 1.6 with the help of [Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html). It will allow you to create a single application compatible with wide range of devices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you can think of them as the same at a conceptual level.